# C# Wrong math result

Tags: c#-4.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double x, y;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Initialize input points to zero
            textBox1.Text = "0";
            textBox2.Text = "0";
            x = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            y = Double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            x = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            y = Double.Parse(textBox2.Text);

            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                x = x / (System.Math.Pow(x, 2) + System.Math.Pow(y, 2));
                y = -y / (System.Math.Pow(x, 2) + System.Math.Pow(y, 2));
                textBox1.Text = x.ToString();
                textBox2.Text = y.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            x = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            y = Double.Parse(textBox2.Text);

            if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                x = x / (System.Math.Pow(x, 2) + System.Math.Pow(y, 2));
                y = -y / (System.Math.Pow(x, 2) + System.Math.Pow(y, 2));
                textBox1.Text = x.ToString();
                textBox2.Text = y.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to "re-simulate" my problem, here's the code. Try put in a value of 1 to each text box and then click the unchecked radiobutton. The expected output on the textbox1 should be 0.5 and textbox2 should give -0.5, but I'm getting -0.8 in textbox2.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Full code sample or it didn't happen.

Comment: Works for me - .NET 4 - result **is** -0.5 ....

Comment: No bug here ([online demo](http://ideone.com/cPSHv), using Jon's code)

Answer (score 4):

**After seeing new code**

Okay, here's a short but complete version of your revised code:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double x = 1;
        double y = 1;
        x = x / (x * x + y * y);
        y = -y / (y * y + x * x);


        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
}
```

Now I get 0.5, -0.8 - and the reason is pretty clear. At the start of the first line of calculation, x and y are both 1, so the expression is:

```
x = 1.0 / (1.0 * 1.0 + 1.0 * 1.0);
```

So x is 0.5. Now that affects the *second* line of calculation, which becomes:

```
y = -1.0 / (1.0 * 1.0 + 0.5 * 0.5)
```

In other words, y = -1.0 / 1.25... which equals -0.8.

I suspect you don't want to assign values to `x` and `y` until you've done *both* calculations, e.g.

```
x2 = x / (x * x + y * y);
y2 = -y / (y * y + x * x);

x = x2;
y = y2;
```

I believe that will fix your problem. It's worth trying to learn how to write a short but complete program to help diagnose this sort of thing though.

---

**Original answer**

Unable to reproduce:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x = 1;
        double y = 1;

        x = -x / ( (x*x) + (y*y) );
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }        
}
```

Result: -0.5

Please try this program yourself, and if it prints -0.5 for you (as I fully expect it to), see if you can come up with a similarly short but complete program which *does* demonstrate the problem. I suspect that in the course of trying to convert your current code to a short but complete program, you'll find the bug.

Comment: Should this be an answer or a comment?

Comment: Other people commented "unable to reproduce"; this is the same idea, but it's impossible to include a properly formatted code sample in a comment, so... :)

Comment: If the answer is that the user is mistaken and there is no problem, then yes, it should be an answer.

Comment: @Gabe: I've posted it as an answer as: a) I have provided the OP with the code I've *tried* to reproduce it with; testing the same code should be the OP's next move; b) I've suggested that the reason that the OP is getting the wrong answer is due to a bug in their code, and a way to find that bug (migrate towards a complete example like this).

Comment: @JonSkeet Here's an [online demo](http://ideone.com/cPSHv) that proves your result (I mean, for the OP of course), If you want to include it in your answer.

Comment: Editted the question with a program which does demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @user1064682: Not really - it's incomplete, so we can't run it. Why introduce a GUI when this is clearly simpler to demonstrate with a console app? I'll try to work out what's going on, but really, a GUI is overkill and makes things harder to diagnose.

Comment: @user1064682: Okay, I've edited my answer. This question is a good demonstration of how important short but complete example programs are.